# Would it more easy to maintain if this is implemented as a class or a function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code:

```
function setSidebar(visible) {
    "use strict"
    if (visible === "show") {
        $("#sidebar-width-switch").prop('title', 'Hide Sidebar');
        $("#sidebar").show();
    } else {
        $("#sidebar-width-switch").prop('title', 'Show Sidebar');
        $("#sidebar").hide();
    }
}
```

With typescript I have seen a lot more use of classes. In this case would it be more easy to maintain if functions like this were implemented as classes and if so then how would I do this and how would I call the class?

Here is how I call this now:

```
    $('#sidebar-width-switch')
        .click(function (e) {
            if ($("#sidebar").is(':hidden')) {
                setSidebar("show");
                localStorage.setItem('Sidebar', 'show');
            } else {
                setSidebar("hide");
                localStorage.setItem('Sidebar', 'hide');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class would allow you to separate the data from the behaviour, a bit like this:

```
class SideBar {
    private sidebarElement: JQuery;
    private switchElement: JQuery;

    constructor(sidebarId: string, switchId: string) {
        this.sidebarElement = $('#' + sidebarId);
        this.switchElement = $('#' + switchId);
    }

    show() {
        this.sidebarElement.show();
        this.switchElement.prop('title', 'Hide Sidebar');
    }

    hide() {
        this.sidebarElement.hide();
        this.switchElement.prop('title', 'Show Sidebar');
    }
}

var sidebar = new SideBar('sidebar', 'sidebar-width-switch');
sidebar.show();
sidebar.hide();
```

This would allow you to use the SideBar class without it being welded to the specific ID and it would allow you to have multiple sidebars on the page, each one being a `new SideBar`.

The constructor ensures that you set up the class with the required data, which means the methods don't need to accept arguments. This reduces repetition in the calling code.

The class is re-usable in many projects, the function is tightly coupled to the specific HTML implementation (the specific ids).

Comment: +1 Steve. Quick question, wouldn't the `.show() / .hide()` interfere with the already established show/hide in jQuery? Or since these are prototypes, do they not call jQuery? (since sidebar itself is not a jQuery object)

Comment: It won't interfere, the sidebar.show() calls the jQuery show function.

Answer (score -2):

Keeping it encapsulated as a function is better.

It's less code to comprehend, it's less ceremony to use.